# Find words in a file then grab the x,y coordinates next to the text

Tags: python, ocr

I am using terrasect ocr to generate a text file from a image. Once that is done the output file contains all the text that terrasect could grab from the image file and it also contains the x,y coordinates of the text.

Here is a small example of the output file:

```
  <p class='ocr_par' dir='ltr' id='par_14' title="bbox 65 1198 2904 1245">
 <span class='ocr_line' id='line_17' title="bbox 65 1198 2904 1245"><span class='ocrx_word' id='word_286' title="bbox 65 1200 287 1237">Tormented</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_287' title="bbox 307 1200 391 1237">Soul</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_288' title="bbox 659 1203 682 1237">2</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_289' title="bbox 805 1203 828 1237">2</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_290' title="bbox 953 1203 1133 1237">Common</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_291' title="bbox 1247 1203 1331 1237"><strong>M13</strong></span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_292' title="bbox 1484 1200 1651 1245"><strong>111/249</strong></span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_293' title="bbox 1690 1198 1729 1237">9</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_294' title="bbox 1922 1200 2143 1237">Tormented</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_295' title="bbox 2164 1200 2248 1237">Soul</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_296' title="bbox 2268 1200 2365 1237">can&#39;t</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_297' title="bbox 2383 1200 2489 1237">block</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_298' title="bbox 2508 1200 2581 1237">and</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_299' title="bbox 2604 1203 2630 1237">is</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_300' title="bbox 2651 1200 2904 1237">unblockable.</span> 
 </span>
</p>

<p class='ocr_par' dir='ltr' id='par_15' title="bbox 65 1263 4323 1312">
 <span class='ocr_line' id='line_18' title="bbox 65 1263 4323 1312"><span class='ocrx_word' id='word_301' title="bbox 65 1265 229 1302">Veilborn</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_302' title="bbox 250 1265 365 1302">Ghoul</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_303' title="bbox 659 1268 682 1302">2</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_304' title="bbox 805 1268 828 1302">2</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_305' title="bbox 953 1268 1182 1302">Uncommon</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_306' title="bbox 1247 1268 1331 1302"><strong>M13</strong></span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_307' title="bbox 1484 1265 1651 1310"><strong>114/249</strong></span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_308' title="bbox 1690 1263 1771 1302">09</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_309' title="bbox 1922 1265 2086 1302">Veilborn</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_310' title="bbox 2107 1265 2222 1302">Ghoul</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_311' title="bbox 2242 1265 2339 1302">can&#39;t</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_312' title="bbox 2357 1265 2677 1302">b|ock.Whenever</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_313' title="bbox 2698 1276 2719 1302">a</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_314' title="bbox 2742 1268 2886 1312">Swamp</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_315' title="bbox 2906 1268 3029 1302">enters</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_316' title="bbox 3047 1265 3110 1302">the</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_317' title="bbox 3130 1265 3328 1302">battlefield</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_318' title="bbox 3349 1265 3464 1302">under</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_319' title="bbox 3484 1276 3573 1312">your</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_320' title="bbox 3594 1265 3747 1310">control,</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_321' title="bbox 3766 1276 3839 1312">you</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_322' title="bbox 3857 1276 3940 1312">may</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_323' title="bbox 3961 1268 4081 1302">return</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_324' title="bbox 4102 1265 4266 1302">Veilborn</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_325' title="bbox 4289 1265 4323 1302">GI</span> 
 </span>
</p>
```

Here are two keywords. one is Tormented Soul and the other is Veilborn Ghoul.

I'm trying to have python open the output file and search for tormented soul then grab the x,y coordinates

which would happen to be 65 1200 287 1237

Thanks for your help aheaad of time. I am brand new to python.

Comment: check out lxml, it provides good xml/html parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use [pyquery](http://pythonhosted.org/pyquery/) for the parsing:

```
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq

html = '''  <p class='ocr_par' dir='ltr' id='par_14' title="bbox 65 1198 2904 1245">
 <span class='ocr_line' id='line_17' title="bbox 65 1198 2904 1245"><span class='ocrx_word' id='word_286' title="bbox 65 1200 287 1237">Tormented</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_287' title="bbox 307 1200 391 1237">Soul</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_288' title="bbox 659 1203 682 1237">2</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_289' title="bbox 805 1203 828 1237">2</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_290' title="bbox 953 1203 1133 1237">Common</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_291' title="bbox 1247 1203 1331 1237"><strong>M13</strong></span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_292' title="bbox 1484 1200 1651 1245"><strong>111/249</strong></span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_293' title="bbox 1690 1198 1729 1237">9</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_294' title="bbox 1922 1200 2143 1237">Tormented</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_295' title="bbox 2164 1200 2248 1237">Soul</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_296' title="bbox 2268 1200 2365 1237">can&#39;t</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_297' title="bbox 2383 1200 2489 1237">block</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_298' title="bbox 2508 1200 2581 1237">and</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_299' title="bbox 2604 1203 2630 1237">is</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_300' title="bbox 2651 1200 2904 1237">unblockable.</span> 
 </span>
</p>

<p class='ocr_par' dir='ltr' id='par_15' title="bbox 65 1263 4323 1312">
 <span class='ocr_line' id='line_18' title="bbox 65 1263 4323 1312"><span class='ocrx_word' id='word_301' title="bbox 65 1265 229 1302">Veilborn</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_302' title="bbox 250 1265 365 1302">Ghoul</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_303' title="bbox 659 1268 682 1302">2</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_304' title="bbox 805 1268 828 1302">2</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_305' title="bbox 953 1268 1182 1302">Uncommon</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_306' title="bbox 1247 1268 1331 1302"><strong>M13</strong></span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_307' title="bbox 1484 1265 1651 1310"><strong>114/249</strong></span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_308' title="bbox 1690 1263 1771 1302">09</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_309' title="bbox 1922 1265 2086 1302">Veilborn</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_310' title="bbox 2107 1265 2222 1302">Ghoul</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_311' title="bbox 2242 1265 2339 1302">can&#39;t</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_312' title="bbox 2357 1265 2677 1302">b|ock.Whenever</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_313' title="bbox 2698 1276 2719 1302">a</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_314' title="bbox 2742 1268 2886 1312">Swamp</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_315' title="bbox 2906 1268 3029 1302">enters</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_316' title="bbox 3047 1265 3110 1302">the</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_317' title="bbox 3130 1265 3328 1302">battlefield</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_318' title="bbox 3349 1265 3464 1302">under</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_319' title="bbox 3484 1276 3573 1312">your</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_320' title="bbox 3594 1265 3747 1310">control,</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_321' title="bbox 3766 1276 3839 1312">you</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_322' title="bbox 3857 1276 3940 1312">may</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_323' title="bbox 3961 1268 4081 1302">return</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_324' title="bbox 4102 1265 4266 1302">Veilborn</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_325' title="bbox 4289 1265 4323 1302">GI</span> 
 </span>
</p>'''
d = pq(html)
```

Then you can do:

```
keyword = 'Tormented Soul'
coords = lambda line: map(int, line('.ocrx_word').eq(0).attr('title').split()[1:])
result = [coords(line) for line in d('.ocr_line').items() if line.text().startswith(keyword)][0]
```

Result:

```
[65, 1200, 287, 1237]
```

EDIT: You can install pyquery with:

```
pip install pyquery
```

if you need to read from a file use:

```
d = pq(filename=path_to_html_file)
```

Comment: How could I search using multiple keywords from a file instead?

Comment: you could wrap the code in a for loop an cycle throw all your keywords.

Comment: also i'm getting this error ImportError: No module named pyquery  I'm running python 2.7

Comment: see my edit to read from a file, you need to install pyquery, `pip install pyquery`